# WinRT HttpClient header Authorization with multiple values

Tags: windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

I need to set the Authorization header for Amazon SQS but it requires multiple values.

When setting the header I get an exception thrown:

> System.FormatException : Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values.

How can I set the header with multiple values separated by a comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked it out, solution is to assign it to the Authorization property.

```
string authorize = "Credential=.../sqs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signature=....";
```

Given the entire string, which contains multiple values:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("AWS4-HMAC-SHA256", authorize);
```

Assign it to the Authorization property.

This solved the problem.