# REST API with C# returns the error Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values

Tags: c#, rest, powerbi

I am working through trying to troubleshoot a REST API that creates a new workspace within the Power BI Service.  However, when I execute the code I get the error message:  *Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values.*

The code I'm using is below:

```
        public static async Task createNewWorkspace(string workspaceName)
        {
            bearer = "";
            workspaceName = "TESTING";
            //Create Workspace 
            var url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups?workspaceV2=True";
            var content = new StringContent("{\"name\": \"" + workspaceName + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("Authorization"))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
            }
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
           var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

after I try to run the var response line it exits with the error mentioned.

I have tried several troubleshooting methods to get rid of this error.  I tried adding the remove statement to check for the authorization and then get rid of it (no luck).

I tried different authorizaiton methods as well such as:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer" + bearer);

or


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearer);

or simply

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
```

Which I have found in different links as well:

[Adding HttpClient headers generates a FormatException with some values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198090/adding-httpclient-headers-generates-a-formatexception-with-some-values)

[WinRT HttpClient header Authorization with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080908/winrt-httpclient-header-authorization-with-multiple-values)

Please let me know if I've overlooked something.  I'm newer to c# as this is one of my first projects I've worked on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Found something odd maybe someone more knowledgeable can explain.

If I call this with this command it works fine (with the removes above):

```
    namespace Learning_TOM
{

    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main()
        {

            await RESTAPI.createNewWorkspace("TEST 10122023 b");
         }
     }
}
```

However, if I call it where I want to (which is from within another area) then I get the error mentioned in this post.

The other area works like this:

```
namespace Learning_TOM
{

    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main()
        {

            //await RESTAPI.createNewWorkspace("TEST 10122023 b");

            DatasetManager.GetCompanyCategoryFormID();


        }


    }
}

THEN IN HERE:

  public static async void GetCompanyCategoryFormID()
  {
      //Connect to SQL Server 
      string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
      SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      sqlConnection.Open();
      Console.WriteLine("Connected to SQL Server");

 
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SQL STATEMENT", sqlConnection))
      {
          using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
              while (reader.Read()) //looping through sql results
              {
                  int companyId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                  string DatabaseName = "Case WorkItems for " + companyId; //Dataset Name
                  //string workspaceName = "LearningTOM"; //Workspace Name
                  string workspaceName = "WORKSPACE FOR - " + companyId; //Workspace Name

                  //check if workspace exists if not create it
                  var targetWorkspace = AnalyticsDataAccess.GetWorkspace(workspaceName);
                  if (targetWorkspace == null)
                  {
                      //workspace doesn't exist
                      
                      await RESTAPI.createNewWorkspace(workspaceName);

                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my latest run I took this snapshot after the remove statement:

[image]

And then after the add statement for the authorization header:

[image]

And then I get the same error message:

[image]

creating HTTP client here

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

EDIT:

I updated the code from a suggestion in the comments from @Brian.  It is creating workspaces but failing at the same time.  It will exit out of the debugger and throw up different errors.  Like "FORBIDDEN".  However, it always creates the workspace before it fails.  Which is odd...

```
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups?workspaceV2=True";
                var content = new StringContent("{\"name\": \"" + workspaceName + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                    Content = content
                };

                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

I did find an 'answer' as well that I will post.

Comment: Are you trying to override authorization header in the http context from client?

Comment: @Jivopis, What do you mean by override?  My understanding of REST API is I need to add my bearer token to the authorization in order for it to work properly.  So I want to place that in the Authorization header for this to succeed.  I just added an Edit.  I found something interesting as I was troubleshooting this.

Comment: if your web api uses bearer authorization scheme, then you are right. Your client should add authorization header(there are few ways to do it) with the Bearer token to the httpContext that it's planning to use for the http/https request with your WEB API.

Comment: How are you creating your `HttpClient`?

Comment: @Brian I apologize for missing that part:  static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Comment: OH!  Does it work on the first call but fail the second time around?  You're adding a *default* header, so that's going to stick around for future calls on the HttpClient.  Still, your call to `Remove` ought to work.  My team runs `httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);`.  We set all our headers on the transient `httpRequestMessage` which avoids issues with `DefaultRequestHeaders` entirely.

Comment: Thanks @Brian i made a change with your suggestion and although it creates the workspace I'm so far not getting a great error message.  I also found a workaround or a fix that I'll post as well.  I made an edit with the changes I made with your suggestion if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a new workspace by replacing the above code with the following:

```
                var client = new RestClient("https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups?workspaceV2=True");
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);

                request.AddJsonBody(new
                {
                    name = workspaceName
                   
                });

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```